# who has the higher probability to buy pizza

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Supposed that A, B, C are given a bunch of homework (N). They decided to share the homework and work individually on each part. A will take 20%, B take 30% and C take 50% of the homework (N).

Because A is a good student so he will make 1% error (doing it wrong) in the homework that he is assigned, B is lazy so he will make 5% and C will make 2%.

1. Supposed that the grader is lazy too. He picks a random homework n in the total N homework without looking at it and marks it as wrong. What is the possibility that n (a random picked homework) is truly wrong?
2. Supposed that the random picked homework n is truly wrong. What is the possibility that A, B, C did that?

Sorry I paraphrase the question (2), it originally said that "Determine who has a higher possibility to buy pizza for other if he is the one who did that wrong homework."

I cannot find a way to solve the number 1. Please advise and help.

Thank you.

Comment: What does pizza have to do with this?

Comment: Or piazza, for that matter?

Comment: Sorry I paraphrase the question (2), it originally said that "Determine who has a higher possibility to buy pizza for other if he is the one who did that wrong homework."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With probability $0.20$, the problem was done by A. **Given that** it was done by A, the probability it was wrong is $0.01$. So the probability the thing was done by A **and** wrong is $(0.2)(0.1)$.

The other two ways the result can be wrong have probabilities $(0.3)(0.05)$ and $(0.5)(0.02)$.

So the probability a randomly chosen question is wrong is $(0.2)(0.01)+(0.3)(0.05)+(0.5)(0.02)$.

**Remark:** You did not ask about the second question. Let $W$ be the event the question is done incorrectly. Let $A$ be the event it was done by A. We want (among other things) $\Pr(A|W)$. For this the conditional probability definition $\Pr(X|Y)=\frac{\Pr(X\cap Y)}{\Pr(Y)}$ will be useful.

Comment: what is Pr(X unions Y) in this case ???

Comment: It is intersection, not union. For $A\cap W$, it is $(0.2)(0.01)$.

Comment: then we are going to have the answer equals to the probability that the homework was done by A $(0.2)(0.01)/(0.01)=0.2$, I'm sorry but I don't think it really make sense to me here. Can you please explain?

Comment: The probability it was done by A, given it is wrong, is $(0.2)(0.01)/p$, where $p$ is the answer to the first question. That answer, as was explained, is the sum of three terms.